# 'Input' does not contain a definition for 'GetMouseButton' how is this possible?

Tags: input, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I've wanted to try developing for touch screen but for some reason it said:

> 'Input' does not contain a definition for 'touched'

Then I tried with the old fashioned way, which worked for me a million times, but now doesn't.

> 'Input' does not contain a definition for 'GetMouseButton'

Does someone know the source of my problem?

```
    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            Debug.Log("Pressed left click.");

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(1))
            Debug.Log("Pressed right click.");

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(2))
            Debug.Log("Pressed middle click.");

    }
```

Comment: Are you using visual studio with the Unity Vs tools?

Comment: I tried both MonoDevelop and VS too. When I write Input. it only suggests the things, which are inherited from Object.

Comment: Did you try to manually include the Unity dll to your project?

Comment: Try deleting all the csproj files and the sln files from your project root and reopen the c# project from within the Unity editor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh my god, I am so stupid.
I've already reinstalled Unity, VS and everything maybe twice.
And I didn't see what caused the problem...
The problem was that I named my script 'Input' 
Oh my GOOOOD