# How to change text in Unity Text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change text in `My_Text` but it doesn't work.
I'm using `UnityEngine.UI.`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class notbugdText : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text My_Text;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        My_Text.text = "Hello world!";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I've got error message: `Assets/scripts/notbugdText.cs(11,11): error CS1061: Type 'Text' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' of type 'Text' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference`

I'm using MonoDevelop-Unity to program in C#

Comment: Do you have a class of yours named "Text" somewhere, that overrides Unity's one? Can you try with `public UnityEngine.UI.Text My_Text;` ?

Comment: thanks that were the problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Input' does not contain a definition for 'GetMouseButton' how is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259270/input-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-getmousebutton-how-is-this-possible)

Comment: @TimHolmqvist You can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Andrea's since that fixed your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment: if you have a class of yours named `Text`, it will override Unity's one. In order to differentiate that, you should declare `My_Text` as:

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Text My_Text;
```

and `using UnityEngine.UI` can be omitted, at this point.